# print the contents of list along with the sublist using spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

how to 
Print the contents of list along with the subList.? can someone help me how to complete service class logic?
question was below Create a program for netplay as below.
    Main List - Categories
    Category sub list - Courses

```
Categories Sample Data: (Add first 3 categories from the netplay app)
 "id": 1001,
 "name": "Computing",
 "description": "network of remote servers"here

Course Sample Data:(Add first 3 courses on every category added from the netplay app)
id : 2001,
Category id: 1001,
name : "AWS"
duration : 180
miles :100
```

This is service class how to implement the logic here to return the content of list along with sublist

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ContentService {

 private List<Category> categories=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Category(1001, "Computing", "network of remote servers"));

//put your code here.
public List<Category> getAllContent() {
    return categories;

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `@RestController` it's already returning a list of `Category` and this category already has inside a list of `Course`s, you need fill your category with courses inside your service.

```
@Service
public class ContentService {
  private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<Category> getAllContent() {
    List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    courses.add(new Course(1, "Coursename", 200, 200, 1001));

    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(new Category(1001, "Computing", "network of remote servers", courses));
    return categories;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the contents of list along with the sub-list dont use

**ArrayList** it will become complex Simply **use the map and put value in map one list as key and **sub-list** as value in map** and print it

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Category> getAllContent() {
List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
courses.add(new Course(2001, "AWS Essentials",180, 100,1001));
    courses.add(new Course(2002, "java ",180, 100,1002));
        courses.add(new Course(2003, "C ",180, 100,1003));
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
categories.add(new Category(1001, "Cloud Computing", "network of remote servers hosted on the Internet to store", courses));
categories.add(new Category(1002, "java", "oops", courses));
categories.add(new Category(1003, "andriod", "mobile", courses));
System.out.println("categoriessize::"+categories.size());
return categories;
```

}