# print contents of a list along with sublist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am trying to add the first 3 Category and add the first 3 courses on each category, but getting stuck on how to add based on condition.

Below is the structure:

```
Categories Sample Data: (Add first 3 categories from the netplay app)
 "id": 1001,
 "name": "Computing",
 "description": "network of remote servers"here

Course Sample Data:(Add first 3 courses on every category added from the netplay app)
id : 2001,
Category id: 1001,
name : "AWS"
duration : 180
miles :100
```

ContentService .java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ContentService {

    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Category> category = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Category> getAllContent() {
        courses.add(new Course(2001,"AWS Essentials",180,100,1001));
        category.add(new Category(1000,"Cloud Compuing","netwoek of remote servers hosted on the internet to store",courses));
        return category;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print the contents of list along with the sublist using spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928961/print-the-contents-of-list-along-with-the-sublist-using-spring-mvc)

Comment: Yes but that question doesn't have correct answer

Comment: "but getting stuck on how to add based on condition": which condition? It is unclear what you are asking.